# Вопрос по Bootstrap'у

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Почему список выстроился столь криво, где я налажал?
Мне нужно чтобы всё это дело стояло по одной линии

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

HTML:

```
          <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2">
          <div class="circlefooter"><p class="oncircle">1</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <p class="howitwork">Кассир пробивает чек. Данные чека попадают в фискальный накопитель<BR>
                            контрольно-кассовой техники и передаются оператору<br>
                            фискальных данных «Такском» через Интернет.</p>
        </div>

      <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2">
          <div class="circlefooter"><p class="oncircle">2</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <p class="howitwork">«Такском» отправляет ответ на кассу о получении информации и одновременно<br>
          передает данные в ФНС. Если у вас пропадает связь, то данные сохраняются<br>
          в фискальном накопителе до 30 дней и отправляются в ОФД сразу же, как только<br>
          связь восстановится.</p>
        </div>

      <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2">
          <div class="circlefooter"><p class="oncircle">3</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <p class="howitwork">Всю информацию о переданных чеках вы в любой момент можете<br>
посмотреть в личном кабинете ОФД Такском. ОФД хранит информацию 5 лет.</p>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.circlefooter {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #7e8aa2;
  border-radius: 50px;
  left: 20%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

p.howitwork {
    color: #263248;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
}

.circlefooter:hover {
  background: #ff9800;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

p.oncircle {
    color: #eee;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    left: 2%;
    cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: у меня неправильно отображается https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XgWvda

Comment: @codename0082016 Вы забыли подключить bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удали:

```
class="col-md-12 col-xs-12"
```

В col-md-12 col-xs-12 присутствуют:

```
padding-right:15px
padding-left:15px
```

на скриншоте они отключены.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]